# Помогите разобраться с перестроением многомерных массивов. Неплохо будет если дадите ссылку по изучению этой темы. Совсем запутался в этих скобках

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Дан список событий за определенные даты, хранящийся в следующей структуре:

```
[
'2019-12-29'=> ['name1', 'name3', 'name5', 'name7'],
'2019-12-30'=> ['name4', 'name8', 'name9'],
'2019-12-31'=> ['name2', 'name6'],
```

Напишите код, которой переделает структуру данных вот в такую:

```
[
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-29',
    'event' => 'name1'
],
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-31',
    'event' => 'name2'
],
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-29',
    'event' => 'name3'
],
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-30',
    'event' => 'name4'
],
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-29',
    'event' => 'name5'
],
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-31',
    'event' => 'name6'
],
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-29',
    'event' => 'name7'
],
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-30',
    'event' => 'name8'
],
[
    'date'  => '2019-12-30',
    'event' => 'name9'
],
```

]
Тут я пытался что то делать. Но нет знаний как это сделать, добавить название для ключей..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно сделать два цикла....один внутри другого...............двумерный массив - это почти всегда двойной цикл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста

```
$items = [
    '2019-12-29'=> ['name1', 'name3', 'name5', 'name7'],
    '2019-12-30'=> ['name4', 'name8', 'name9'],
    '2019-12-31'=> ['name2', 'name6']
    ];

$result = [];
foreach ($items as $date => $events) {
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $result[] = [
            'date' => $date,
            'event' => $event
        ];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

[Тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php) можно почитать про массивы в php